# change the background color of zend form elements if invalid

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hi I am using Zend Framework and would like to have my form show which elements are invalid by changing their background color to red.  To do this I need to set the class/id of the invalid `<input class='error'>` in my form and write a css to change the color.  I am just having trouble getting a list of all the invalid elements.

The only way I can think of doing this is after the for is found to be invalid `if (!$form->isValid($posts)){}` is to use `getMessages()` to get the names of all the invalid elements and then set all elements `$element->setAttrib('class', 'error')`.  I was hoping to be able to call something built in to the form, similar to `getElements()` but couldnt find a `getInvalidElements()` or something similar.  I also imagine it would be possible to write a decorator to the whole form to achieve the same thing but I dont know where to start.

Any recommendations on how i should proceed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Zend_Form` and add a css class `error` to all invalid fields, write styles for the `.error` class.

This [blog post](http://blog.mennowolvers.nl/post/7222195602/form-element-error-class-zend-framework) gives you an idea of how it could be done.

Comment: champion! that is exactly what i was looking for.